# Javascript pattern matching a variable

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, matching

I am struggling with working out a way to get a pattern match of a variable.  I have tried splitting things and doing an indexOf, using match, and a switch (true) statement, all with little success.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
currentExports = 'sec=sys,rw=badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com,root=badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com';
badExportHosts = params.badExportHosts.split(':');
for (badHost = 0; badHost < badExportHosts.length; badHost++) {
    if (!currentExports.match(/badExportHosts[badHost]/g)) {
        printf('Entry ' + badExportHosts[badHost] + ' was not found in ' + currentExports + '\n');
    } else {
        printf('Entry ' + badExportHosts[badHost] + ' was found in ' + currentExports + '\n');
    }
```

If I enter into my form:

```
badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com
```

I unfortunately get this result:

```
Entry badhost1.foo.com was not found in sec=sys,rw=badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com,root=badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com
Entry badhost2.foo.com was not found in sec=sys,rw=badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com,root=badhost1.foo.com:badhost2.foo.com
```

How can I get this to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your intention here doesn't seem clear enough, but, if I understood it correctly, and all you want is to check wether your "badHost" strings are contained anywhere on currentExports, you could try replacing this:

```
if (!currentExports.match(/badExportHosts[badHost]/g)) {
```

for this:

```
if (currentExports.indexOf(badExportHosts[badHost]) < 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks - This is working, not sure what I was doing wrong the first time I tried indexOf, but it wasn't matching properly.  I'll go back to my main code and see if I have something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Try using a `RegExp` object like this:

```
var pattern;
currentExports = //your same code goes here
//...
for(badHost = 0; badHost < badExportHosts.length; badHost++){
    pattern = new RegExp(badExportHosts[badHost], 'g');
    if (!currentExports.match(pattern)) {
        //your print statments go here
    }
}
```

The problem is your call to `match()` is literally trying to match the string "badExportHosts[badHosts]" on each iteration of the `for` loop , which is no good since you need to match the values in your `badExportHosts` array, and not the variable name itself.  You need a regex like `/badhost1.foo.com/g`, which the `RegExp` object gives you.

Comment: Great, this works also.  First I have seen RegExp, works great!